# Example of projective variety that do not contain algebraic curves of genus strictly greater to $1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, projective-geometry, genus

Does exist a smooth, complex, projective variety $X$ of dimension $d\geq2$ such that $X$ does not contain smooth, complex, projective curves of wichever genus $g\geq2$?

**Answer by Bertie**: No, it does not exists.

More in general, does previous statement hold for $X$ over any field of characteristic $0$?

**Partial Answer**: If the field is algebraically closed: no, it does not.

**Open question**: Does exist a smooth projective variety $X$ of dimension $d\geq2$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ not algebraically closed of characteristic $0$, such that $X$ does not contain smooth projective curves of wichever genus $g\geq2$?

Comment: Could you please clarify: are you fixing $g$ and then asking for fixed $g$ whether there exists a smooth projective variety that contains no curve of genus $g$?  The answer to that is yes, e.g., any simple Abelian variety of dimension $>g$.  However, by the adjunction formula, the genera of complete intersection curves of sufficiently ample divisors are arbitrarily positive.  So every projective variety of dimension $\geq 2$ contains curves of unbounded genera.

Answer (score 8):

Every smooth projective variety of dimension at least 2 over an algebraically closed field contains curves of arbitrarily large genus.

(Choose an ample line bundle $L$ on $X$ and consider the embeddings $X \hookrightarrow \mathbf P^{N_d}$ given by tensor powers $L^d$; a general linear section of $X$ of the appropriate codimension is then a smooth curve of genus $g(d)$, where $g(d)$ grows without bound as a function of $d$.)

Comment: As usual, Jason Starr got there before me...

Comment: Thank you!, and over a field of characteristic $0$ and not algebraically closed?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos This argument works over any infinite field, and with Poonen's Bertini theorem will work over finite fields.